# Can anyone tell me what's the problem with this javaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
function fun() {
    
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var admin = "admin";
    var user = "user";
    var master = "master";
    
    if (name == "") {
      alert("PLEASE ENTER YOUR UID and PASSWORD");
    }
    else if (name == user){
      window.location.href = "form1.html";
    }
    else if (name == admin) {
      window.location.href = "admin.html"
    }
    else if (name == master){
      window.location.href = "master-admin.html"
    }
    else{
      alert("Please give a valid id");
    }
  }
```

The form code is here: -

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" id="name" required/>
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required/>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" onclick="fun()">LOGIN</button><br />
    <button type="button">SIGN UP</button><br />
</form>
```

I am trying to navigate to 3 different pages with 3 different credentials but during login it is not navigating to any of the pages. Please tell me the mistake I am doing ....

Comment: You need to add "/"(forward slash) while assigning URL to  window.location.href.
For Example: 
window.location.href = "/form1.html";

Comment: You can just change the button type to 'button' for the Login button.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code.
But the result is good.
Are you sure if form1.html, admin.html and master-admin.html is in same directory with that html containing fun function?
I think there is a error.
Please check.